# Count categories but exclude option

Tags: wordpress, count, categories

I added a new checkbox in the categories interface called **is_a_city** so I can easily identify which categories are cities. This works well. These get stored in the options table with a value of 1 is it is a city:

[image]

But on the front-end I need to be able to return a count of all categories that are **not** cities.

So I have this code that counts all categories and displays the total...

```
$args = array( 
    'parent'        => 0, 
    'hide_empty'    => 0
);
$all_cats = get_categories( $args );
echo count( $all_cats );
```

...but I don't know how to get the count to **exclude** the categories that were marked **is_a_city**.

Comment: Is is_a_city=0 means category?

Comment: `is_city_97` with `option_value` 1 means category 99 is a city.

Comment: Saving that as an option seems odd, there's term meta data you can use which would make this whole thing much simpler... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta

Comment: Agreed. However the theme in question has been set up like this for years (a project inherited) and the data has been stored that way, and it's what we have to work with.